# PERCENTILE_CONT for median and rounding value to 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm able to select median values using PERCENTILE_CONT, but I also want the values to only contain 4 decimal places.

When I do this I get an error saying:

> 'PERCENTILE_CONT' must have an OVER clause.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    FIELD1,
    CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FIELD1) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1) AS Median
FROM
    TABLE1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error implies `PERCENTILE_CONT` is not a stand alone function.
You need to cast the whole block of keywords

```
CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FIELD1) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1) AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS Median
```